Картинки съезжают влево во флексе, когда ставлю margin-left: auto и margin-right: auto всё слипается в одно, но зато по центру. Как решить проблемы?
Картинки съезжают влево во флексе, когда  ставлю margin-left: auto и margin-right: auto всё слипается в одно, но зато по центру. Как решить проблемы?
по итогу мне нужно получить картинки, которые равномерно разбрасываются по блоку шириной 650px


.second {
    margin-top: 106px;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.skills > p {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-family: Seymour One;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height:25px;
    letter-spacing: 0%;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    margin-top: 35px;
}
.svg_skills > img {
    width: 90px;
    height: 136px;
}
.svg_skills > img:first-child {
    width: 70px;
    height: 115px;
}
.svg_skills {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    max-width: 650px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
h1 {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-family: Seymour One;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 40px;
    letter-spacing: 0%;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
<div class="second">
                <div class="skills">
                    <h1>Скиллы</h1>
                    <p>Здесь будет ваш текст
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="svg_skills">
                    <img src="img/figma.svg">
                    <img src="img/vscode.svg">
                    <img src="img/true.svg">
                </div>
            </div>




Задайте width: 100%;

помогло, спасибо!

Вам нужно добавить width блоку и параметр justify-content для flex
у меня получилось вот так


.svg_skills {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 650px;
  width: 100%; /*длина блока ограниченная 650px*/
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: space-between;/*Распределение по всей длине блока*/
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}



